# Jacobian matrix of $F(x,y)=(ye^{f(x,x)},f(y,0)+\sin f(x,y))$ doubt

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I'm considering $f \in C^1(R^2 )$ scalar field and $f(0)=0 $
and $F:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$ $$F(x,y)=(ye^{f(x,x)},f(y,0)+\sin f(x,y))$$
I need to find the jacobian matrix. I did the usual calculations of derivatives and I found:
$$
JF(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}
        ye^{f(x,x)}f_{x}(x,x) & e^{f(x,x)} \\
        \cos f(x,y)f_{x}(x,y) & f_{y}(0,y)+\cos f(x,y)f_{y}(x,y) \\
         \end{pmatrix}
$$
However I kwon that the correct result is: $$
JF(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}
        ye^{f(x,x)}(f_{x}(x,x)+f_{y}(x,x)) & e^{f(x,x)} \\
        \cos f(x,y)f_{x}(x,y) & f_{x}(0,y)+\cos f(x,y)f_{y}(x,y) \\
         \end{pmatrix}
$$
I can't understand why in the first element of the first row a partial derivative respect to y appears and the same respect to x in the second element of the second row. I don't know whethere it is a conceptual mistake.

Can you help me?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

It seems unnecessarily confusing to label the inputs of $f$ and $F$ with the same labels – I suspect that you'd have gotten the right answer yourself if you'd labeled the inputs of $f$ e.g. as $u$ and $v$ – it's then straightforward to see that both $f_u$ and $f_v$ must appear in the top left entry (since both $u$ and $v$ vary as $x$ varies).